# Part of JS code not working for photo gallery

Tags: javascript

I have a photo gallery in JavaScript, using Nuxt.js. For more information, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73742546/simplify-js-code-using-nuxt-js-not-working). 
Here is the new code :

```js
  // Open PopUp
  const photoGalleryFullscreen = document.querySelector(".photo-gallery-fullscreen");
  const imagesFullscreen = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-container img");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < imagesFullscreen.length; i++) {
    photo[i].onclick = function() {
      photoGalleryFullscreen.style.display = "block";
      imagesFullscreen[i].style.display = "block";
      slideIndex = i;
    }

      // Close PopUp
    document.querySelector(".out").onclick = function() {
      photoGalleryFullscreen.style.display = "none";
      imagesFullscreen[i].style.display = "none";
      slideIndex = 1;
    };
  }
```

In the last part of the new code (//Close PopUp) this is not working (the rest is working), if you can help (thank you very much) :

```js
      imagesFullscreen[i].style.display = "none";
```

On contrary, if I set manually i, it is working for the selected image

Comment: Click handler for ```.out``` is working correctly? I mean, is it being called on click?

Comment: Yes because the rest of the code is working.

Comment: what is the value if ```i``` when you are trying to set display style to none?

Comment: It is always 2.

Comment: Is that intended? Do you want to hide the third item only?

Comment: No, I want to hide the element that was displayed in block after click on the little photo.

Comment: either hide all of the item and if that's not intended then check each item which has display style as block then hide that particular item.

Comment: But the problem is that we can’t apply style.display to several elements. Normally i should change value according to the little photo click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248173/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-mh-info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to determine which image is clicked and save it in a variable.
Here is the new code that is working :

```js
  const photoGalleryFullscreen = document.querySelector(".photo-gallery-fullscreen");
  const imagesFullscreen = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-container img");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < imagesFullscreen.length; i++) {
    // Open PopUp
    photo[i].onclick = function() {
      photoGalleryFullscreen.style.display = "block";
      imagesFullscreen[i].style.display = "block";
      globalThis.imageClickedNumber = i;
      slideIndex = i;

      document.body.setAttribute("class", "disable-scroll");
    }

    // Close PopUp
    document.querySelector(".out").onclick = function() {
      if (imagesFullscreen[imageClickedNumber].style.display == "block") {
      photoGalleryFullscreen.style.display = "none";
      imagesFullscreen[imageClickedNumber].style.display = "none";
      slideIndex = 1;

      document.body.removeAttribute("class");
      }
    };
  }
```